# How to change the position of the line

Tags: spacing, line

From the following code the line goes up to only certain height and then it does not go up or change even if I use negative vspace. I want the line to reach the top of the book.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}


\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \color{white}%
    \rule{\pdfpagewidth}{\dimexpr\pdfpageheight-6in}%
  }
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{blue}
\color{white}% Set text colour
\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{14cm}\vspace{-5cm}\draw[ultra thick] (0,-7) -- (0,15);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\vspace` works like `\vadjust{\vskip...}` in LaTeX. it means that the vertical skip is realized after the horizontal line (where `\vadjust` is used) is printed. Idea: insert `\vskip` before your tikzpicture. But there is another issue: TeX ignores vertical glue at the beginning of the page. But there is the macro `\vglue` which inserts an invisible node before `\vskip`, so the `\vskip` is not the first node on the page and it is not ignored.

First, do vertical shift, then horizontal shift. The reason is: TeX starts in vertical mode first. You can try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \color{white}%
    \rule{\pdfpagewidth}{\dimexpr\pdfpageheight-6in}%
  }
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{blue}
\color{white}% Set text colour
\vglue-5cm
\hskip14cm
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (0,-7) -- (0,15);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For LaTeX, `\vspace*` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help!